# Fluent Validation - Is there a way to run async action on When?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am trying to display the error message from DB so this is what I got so far:

```
        When(c => c.Type.Equals("new"), async () =>
        {
            var errors = await _repository.ErrorsRepository.Get();


            RuleFor(c => c.AnotherProperty)
                            .NotNull()
                            .WithMessage("Must select Yes or No for '" +
                            $"{errors.FirstOrDefault(l => l.id.Equals("anotherProperty"))?.error}'");
            RuleFor(c => c.AnotherProperty2)
                            .NotNull()
                            .WithMessage("Must select Yes or No for '" +
                            $"{errors.FirstOrDefault(l => l.id.Equals("anotherProperty2"))?.error}'");
            RuleFor(c => c.AnotherProperty3)
                            .NotNull()
                            .WithMessage("Must select Yes or No for '" +
                            $"{errors.FirstOrDefault(l => l.id.Equals("anotherProperty3"))?.error}'");

        });
```

When I run validateAsnc(), I get the following error:

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending.

I am assuming is due to the async action.

EDIT Running Validation:

```
   ...       
   var validator = new objValidator();
   var validationTask = validator.ValidateAsync(obj);

    ModelState.Clear();

    var result =  await validationTask;           
    result.AddToModelState(ModelState, null);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    ...
```

Comment: Ho do you run `ValidateAsync`, code please

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, added how i run `ValidateAsnc`.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late reply, but I believe this is what you're looking for that I've found here
https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1300#issuecomment-579940908

```
WhenAsync(async (x, ct) => await SomeConditionCheck(), () => {
  RuleFor(x => x.Forename).CustomAsync(async (value, context, ct) => {
    string message = await GetMessage();
    context.AddFailure(message);
  });
});
```